# Bootstrap Collapse - No Animation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing Bootstrap Collapse to my website by clicking an icon from the Font Awesome library. When I press it, the content collapses, but there is no animation, it just pops up. What am I doing wrong?

Here's [my code](https://www.bootply.com/R3kzA3gO0F)

```
<div class="container col-sm-12 banner">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#moreInfo"></i>
</div>
<div id="moreInfo" class="collapse">
    <div class="hiddenInfo">
                123
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a conflict due to your improper implementation of Bootstrap's Grid system.  `.container` and `.col-sm-12` cannot be combined in this fashion; it results in a series of floating errors that conflicts with the transition effect.

Once you correctly implement Bootstrap's Grid (and address clear issues with your other `float`) the transition animates as expected.

```css
.banner {
  background-color: #1194f0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.banner i {
  font-size: 40px;
  float: right;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.hiddenInfo {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="banner clearfix">
        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#moreInfo"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div id="moreInfo" class="collapse">
        <div class="hiddenInfo">
          123
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```